# Gstreamer elements not appearing available in c program but they do appear available using gst-tools

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, gstreamer

I have a c++ program using gstreamer. The problem is that several of my elements--namely the ffmpeg plugins--do not work in the program. However when I run for example:

```
gst-inspect | grep ffenc_h261   It shows up.
```

If I run `gst-launch .... ! ffenc_h261 ! ...` , it works.

However in my application, I always receive element 'ffenc_h261' not found or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That is all the info needed to explain. gst_parse_launch and gst_element_factory_make fails on a pipeline using the ffmpeg codecs but not the other plugins. I am certain that the pipeline is correct and that the code is correct. I am also certain that the plugins are installed. My question is mainly how to fix my install of gstreamer or which environment variables I need to check on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my distro was all flubbed up. I uninstalled everything that uses gstreamer, sudo apt-get purge gstreamer*, then downloaded all of the source, compiled, and installed. It was a real pain in the ass, but I got it working. One more reason that most package managers are nice, but are no substitute for knowing how to use a compiler and make.

The most annoying thing about both yum and apt is that when they are installing something like gst-ffmpeg-plugins, the package manager does not tell you that it is disabling certain features bacause another feature isn't installed.

Maybe I should complain about that to debian. Anyways, reading the output of ./configure is the way to go.